# How to deploy an App into Google Play by packaging using Titanium Studio?

Tags: titanium-mobile, google-play

I have created an android application in Titanium Studio, with some research i found i should be uploading `app.apk` file under `/build/android/bin` directory in Google play store to publish the application.

But when i uploaded my `app.apk` file in Google play store, it showed like below

[image]

and shows this app supports 0 device as below

[image]

What am i doing wrong? do i have to follow any further steps before i upload the app.apk file? right now i am just building the app and take the `app.apk` file from buid directory.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i sorted this issue. I need to activate the `app.apk` file, only then it
shows the number of device supported.

Posting answer as someone might find it useful.